# when assigning a string to a union member defined as char name[20] it will not compile

Tags: c, char, union

> I'm working with an example from a video C programming tutorial and it will not compile. I'm getting an error message error:
> error: assignment to expression with array type
> unionVar.name = "Bill can code";
> ^
> I've tried using & an * in different spots but obviously I am missing something very simple..

```
 #include <stdio.h>

union myFirstUnion {
    int i;
    float f;
    char name[20];
} unionVar;   

int main() {
    unionVar.i = 10;
    printf("%d ", unionVar.i);
    printf("\n");
    unionVar.name = "Bill can code";
    printf("%s ", unionVar.name);
    printf("\n");
    unionVar.f = 10.0;
    printf("%f ", unionVar.f);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

> I have tried making a 'char *name{20];' declaration but I get a different error message when trying to assign the string. My internet search didn't produce any insights.  Please help if you can.  Thank you so very much.

Comment: `strcpy(unionVar.name, "Bill can code")`

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being in a union — you cannot reassign arrays in C.

Comment: `"Bill can code"` isn't assignable to `char name[20];` when you make that assignment you are really setting the address of the first element, which is in part of memory that is const...

Comment: @kaylum This complies and works (strcpy(unionVar.name, "Bill can code") ) Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign an array in C.

You could strncpy to write to it, for instance:

```
strncpy(unionVar.name, "Bill can code", sizeof(unionVar.name) - 1);
unionVar.name[sizeof(unionVar.name) - 1] = '\0';
```